# Не работает ЧПУ на ngnix

Tags: rewrite

Такая конструкция в конфиге, но на сайте ничего не меняется, чпу не работают - 404 ошибка

```
location ~ \.php$ 
    {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;

        rewrite ^/?(news)/?$ /?page=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/nauka-i-tekhnika.html$ /?page=news&type=list&id=18 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/obshchestvo/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=11&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/politika/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=12&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/ekonomika/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=13&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/proisshestviya/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=14&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/kultura/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=15&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/istoriya/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=16&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/sport/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=17&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/nauka-i-tekhnika/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&type=list&id=18&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/page([0-9]*).html?$ /?page=news&p=$1 break;
        rewrite ^/?news/(.*).html?$ /?page=news&type=item&n=$1 break;

    }

    location = /?news/obshchestvo.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=11 break; } 
    location = /?news/politika.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=12 break; } 
    location = /?news/ekonomika.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=13 break; }
    location = /?news/proisshestviya.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=14 break; }
    location = /?news/kultura.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=15 break; } 
    location = /?news/istoriya.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=16 break; }
    location = /?news/sport.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=17 break; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что дело в:

- несоответствии `location` и `rewrite`;
- лишних символах `?` в `location`.

Пример несоответствия `location` и `rewrite`:

```
rewrite ^/?(news)/?$ /?page=$1 break;
```

- предполагает обращение по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:9000/news`.
- с перенаправлением на страницу `http://127.0.0.1:9000/?page=news`.
- правило находится в области, ограниченной `~ \.php$`.

Пусть пользователь перешел по адресу `http://127.0.0.1:9000/index.php`. Location подходящий - `~ \.php$`. Но `http://127.0.0.1:9000/index.php` не будет соответствовать правилу замены `http://127.0.0.1:9000/news` и наоборот.

Пример лишних символов `?` в location:

```
location = /?news/obshchestvo.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=11 break; }
```

Используйте правила, без лишних `?`:

```
location = /news/obshchestvo.html { rewrite ^(.*)$ /?page=news&type=list&id=11 break; }
```

Посмотрите примеры в документации:

- http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#aio
- http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite